# Hyper-v on vmware

Tags: vmware-esx, hyper-v

We're having a discussion here about Hyper-V and vmware.  Am I right in thinking that ESX and Hyper-V are competing technologies and it is not possible or desirable to run hyper-v on a box virtualized on ESX?  Is this because the machines vmware emulates do not have virtualized implementations of the process virtualization support?

Comment: Can you list **one** compelling reason to do this?

Comment: No I cannot.  I believe people here wish to experiment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Hyper-V and VMware ESX are competing technologies.  I don't think there's anything preventing you from running one on top of the other (you can run VMware on a machine that does not support hardware virtualization), but I don't know why you would want to.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 2008 will not let you add the hyper-V role to a machine running in ESXI.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right in thinking that ESX and
>   Hyper-V are competing technologies and
>   it is not possible or desirable to run
>   hyper-v on a box virtualized on ESX?
>   Is this because the machines vmware
>   emulates do not have virtualized
>   implementations of the process
>   virtualization support?

Yes, running a virtual machine (such as Hyper-V on Win2k8) as a guest vm inside VMWare ESX host is *not* a good idea. Not (*only*) because they're competitors, but technically there's a lot of work the processors do behind the scenes using nested page tables. To cut to the chase, an article ([link](http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/news/article/0,289142,sid94_gci1322012,00.html)) briefly explains the benefits:

> .. when virtualization is thrown into
>   the mix, address translation becomes a
>   challenge because virtual machines
>   (VMs) don't have native direct access
>   to the host server memory..
>
> With nested paging, a page table in
>   the hardware takes care of the
>   translation between the guest address
>   of a VM and the physical address,
>   reducing overhead, Mueting said.

Creating a virtual machine that hosts another virtual machine *I think* would be extremely detrimental to overall performance. Granted I think if you wanted to host Hyper-V within ESX, it *should* be feasible but I would argue it would be a waste of resources.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether or not this would work or not, but I can't think of a reason why anyone would want to.  There would almost certainly be a negative impact running hyper-v on ESX as I am sure then virtual processors wouldn't provide any Intel/AMD VT support.

Comment: Opps Rob beat me to the punch